# how can i create a grid view using jquery or phonegap?

Tags: jquery, cordova

**i want to display some list of alphabets in a grid view using jquery or phonegap,when i click on each alphabet it has to retrieve data from the database based on alphabet series..how can i do this?

here is my database
/**

```
  function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ALLWORDS (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Word TEXT NOT NULL, Type_Of_Word TEXT NOT NULL,Meaning TEXT,Synonym TEXT,Example TEXT,Starred BOOL)');

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain it better? and add an example?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Writing the SQL or creating the view?

Comment: well,i'm having my local database,so in that some list of rows are there like word,meaning,synonym etc,i want to retrieve the data based on word selection,for that i want to display alphabets in a grid view as above screenshot..

Comment: ya i want to create like this as a view,we have to give a link for each word..

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this jquery plugin: http://www.trirand.com/blog/ it will create a nice grid view based on json data. Lots of nice features.